# How to use a many to many relationship in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony

I am working on a `Symfony 2` based web app and struggling to create a many to many relationship between to entities:

Each `Task` entity should be assigned to any number of `Categories`. Of course each `Category` can be used by any number of `Task` entities. While a `Task` needs to know its `Categories` the `Category` class has no relationship back to the `Tasks`.

Following [this tutorial](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep3/many-to-many-relationship) I created:

```
class Task {    
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="categories")
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Category")
    */
    protected $categories;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->productVariations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        ...
    }
}
```

Which results in the following SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE task ... categories VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, ...
```

A new `Task` is created use a form with the following type:

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('categories', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle:Category',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ))
            ...
    }
}
```

Submitting the form and persiting the new `Task`instance result in a SQL row with the following content in the `categories`column:

```
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@000000007448a17a0000000048941f2f
```

**What does this mean?** Storing the referenced `Category` entities as array is not normal form but of course valid (in fact I would prefer this solution over adding a relationship table since in practice the number of categories per task will be quite small, thus a third table would be more overhead).

However I would assume that the array stores the IDs of the referenced objects/rows in some form. How would it be possible to store any number of references in a `VARCHAR(255)` column?

While submitting and persisting creates a DB entry, the `Category` references are not stored correctly. When I try to re-read this entry, the `categories` property is empty.

Comment: Why not using [this](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/collections) tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have redundant column definition. Try to simply remove following line:

```
* @ORM\Column(name="categories")
```

Then you need to update you database schema.

This line creates a `varchar` field  in task table which shouldn't be there. Many to many relations are implemented via separate table.

If you want to store ids in a single field instead of separate table, then you will handle it on your own. That's because it won't be able to be a relation anymore. You loose possibility to create foreign key or doing any join queries. Also filtering records will be harder to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing something here.

Like you said, a `Task` can be associated to many `Category`(ies) AND the `Category` class DOES NOT need a relational mapping to the `Task` class.

All you need in your `Task` class is a property to reference your Categories.

I think what you're looking for is [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional).